# What is islambda function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can anyone help me understanding this:

```
def isalambda(v):
    return isinstance(v, type(lambda: None)) and v.__name__ == '<lambda>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function tests if a function object was created using a `lambda` statement:

```
>>> l = lambda: None
>>> l
<function <lambda> at 0x1020ae0c8>
>>> l.__name__
'<lambda>'
```

`lambda` expressions create a regular function object with the name set to `<lambda>` as there is no `def` statement naming the function.

It could just as well have used:

```
from types import FunctionType

def isalambda(v):
    return isinstance(v, FunctionType) and v.__name__ == '<lambda>'
```

or using [`inspect.isfunction()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction):

```
from inspect import isfunction

def isalambda(v):
    return isfunction(v) and v.__name__ == '<lambda>'
```

The test isn't foolproof; you can assign any string to the `__name__` attribute:

```
>>> def foo(): pass
... 
>>> foo.__name__
'foo'
>>> foo.__name__ = '<lambda>'
>>> foo.__name__
'<lambda>'
>>> foo
<function <lambda> at 0x1020ae050>
```

Comment: Or `return inspect.isfunction(v) and v.__name__ == '<lambda>'`